# Why can a protected field be access from a class that is not a subtype?

Tags: java, protected, access-modifiers

I have wired problem. I have this class:

```
public class Player {
...
     protected int x;
}
```

and in another test-class (which **not** extends Player):

```
    Player p = new Player("gfdg");
    p.x = 10;
    System.out.println(p.x);
```

^ it's actually work!

why java treat the protected as public?

Comment: Classes in same package? Nothing Eclipse-specific.

Comment: Can you provide full code? It doesn't show me package name.

Comment: They must be in the same package.

Answer (score 1):

Protected fields are visible within the package.